# AWS - ELB - Puppet - Must not contain unprintable characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, puppet, puppetmaster

I am setting up a miscellaneous server cluster behind an internal AWS ELB which will serve NTP, centralized Rsyslog, and Puppetmaster. I configured the listener on the ELB to use https (8140) which required a certificate, so I used aws cli to upload the certs, and they uploaded fine:

```
"ServerCertificateMetadata": {
    "ServerCertificateId": "SOMEID",
    "ServerCertificateName": "wildcard_example_com",
    "Expiration": "2016-09-14T23:59:59Z",
    "Path": "/",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::1234:server-certificate/wildcard_example_com",
    "UploadDate": "2015-10-21T13:46:22.844Z"
}
```

But now when I try to run puppet against a node I keep getting these errors:

```
Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Certname "/ou=domain control validated/ou=positivessl wildcard*.example.com" must not contain unprintable or non-ASCII characters
```

The .crt and .key files were uploaded as is, which I assume was already in PEM format, b/c when I view them they have the following:

```
# server.key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<key string here>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

# server.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<crt string here>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

If I add `127.0.0.1 puppetmaster` to the `/etc/hosts` file (circumventing the ELB) then puppet runs fine. What am I missing?

Versions:

```
CentOS: 6.7
Puppetmaster: 2.7.26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use SSL-offload on the ELB - you can just use standard port passthrough and leave everything as-is.

e.g. Traffic on TCP port 8140 traffic on the ELB is forwarded to port 8140 on the Puppet master.

Comment: Ahhh so don't even use https? Ya it works fine as TCP.

Comment: Yep I know how this works